# Finding smaller numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
for i in range(len(b)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(b)):
        if b[i]>b[j]:
            count+=1
```

This is the Code I've written to find how many small numbers are there in a list after each no in a list.Can anyone give the solution in O(n) complexity??

Comment: If you make a web search of "Search Algorithms" you will take many results that will give you the answer. Also I would recommend you to search for "Data Structures", there are some structures that are sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first start with sorting the list using b_sorted=sorted(b)